# Problem with dropdown list working with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, select, dropdown

I'm trying to select an element from a dropdown list, but I got this error in the execution:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='id12']"}

The HTML code of the dropdown list is:

```html
<select style="width:163px" name="department:department" id="id12">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Escoge</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="999">999</option>
    <option value="800">800</option>
    <option value="700">700</option>
    <option value="600">600</option>
    <option value="540">540</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
    <option value="345">345</option>
    <option value="280">280</option>
    <option value="270">270</option>
    <option value="264">264</option>
    <option value="262">262</option>
    <option value="251">251</option>
    <option value="201">201</option>
    <option value="82">82</option>
    <option value="81">81</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="001">001</option>
</select>
```

My java code is:

```java
WebElement dropdownlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='id12']"));
Select dropdown = new Select(dropdownlist);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("100");
```

I've tried with this too:

```java
WebElement dropdownlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='department']"));
Select dropdown = new Select(dropdownlist);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("100");

WebElement dropdownlist = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id='id12']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly id is **dynamic** here and **name** attribute value you have provided is wrong.

Try the below code.

```
WebElement dropdownlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='department:department']"));
Select dropdown = new Select(dropdownlist);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("100");
```

Comment: i got this error with your solution: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@name='department:department']"}

Comment: Check if the drop down present inside an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

To deal with dropdown you have to use `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`import and it will nstantiate the drop-down box as a "Select" object in WebDriver. Also it could be possible that element on which you are trying to perform action taking time and hence the exception occurred. Add Explicit wait and check from your end ::

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("id12"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
Select dropdown = new Select(element);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("100");
```

Comment: i have this issue: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#id12"}

Comment: Can you please share your url ,if no then check availability of iframe and use below code to switch to iframe before you handling Select web element.  ::: driver.switchTo().frame("id of the element")